# Another heroku code=H10 error.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm following Michael Hartls tutorial for Ruby on Rails Web Development and reached the end of Chapter 7 regarding sign ups (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-tests_for_user_signup).

Launching the application on my localhost works fine and launching it onto Heroku worked up to this chapter, however now I get H10 errors.

I have reviewed the heroku logs and I don't appear to have any syntax or un-installed gemfiles. I also ran heroku run rake db:migrate before opening the site on heroku. However I still get the same error.

If you can, any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

```
    2013-06-29T09:04:54.821851+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-29T09:04:55.046955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047372+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.046955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047983+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.046955+00:00 app[web.1]:   See everything in the log (default is :info)
2013-06-29T09:04:55.046955+00:00 app[web.1]:                    ^
2013-06-29T09:04:55.046955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.046955+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /app/config/environments/production.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected keyword_in, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
2013-06-29T09:04:55.046955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.046955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.046955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.046955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.068195+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.068195+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047983+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.047831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-06-29T09:04:55.068195+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-06-29T09:04:55.068195+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-06-29T09:04:55.068195+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:37944
2013-06-29T09:04:56.568729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-06-29T09:04:56.582829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-06-29T09:04:43+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-06-29T09:04:57.782340+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=pacific-dawn-2489.herokuapp.com fwd="109.78.252.61" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-06-29T09:04:57.994965+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=pacific-dawn-2489.herokuapp.com fwd="109.78.252.61" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-06-29T09:10:58.047688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-06-29T09:11:06.335632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 24215`
2013-06-29T09:11:17.398786+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-29T09:11:17.398207+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-29T09:11:17.398518+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-29T09:11:19.607748+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-06-29T09:11:18.240845+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.240707+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /app/config/environments/production.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected keyword_in, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
2013-06-29T09:11:18.240707+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.240845+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.252865+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.252865+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:24215
201
3-06-29T09:11:18.241002+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.240707+00:00 app[web.1]:   See everything in the log (default is :info)
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.240845+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.252865+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-06-29T09:11:18.252865+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-06-29T09:11:18.240707+00:00 app[web.1]:                    ^
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.241446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-06-29T09:11:18.252865+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-06-29T09:11:19.595243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-06-29T09:11:48.220707+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by markmurray406@gmail.com
2013-06-29T09:11:52.813935+00:00 heroku[run.9768]: Awaiting client
2013-06-29T09:11:52.839976+00:00 heroku[run.9768]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-06-29T09:11:54.059389+00:00 heroku[run.9768]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-29T09:11:58.081983+00:00 heroku[run.9768]: Process exited with status 1
2013-06-29T09:11:58.103006+00:00 heroku[run.9768]: State changed from up to complete
2013-06-29T09:12:38.785250+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=pacific-dawn-2489.herokuapp.com fwd="109.78.252.61" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-06-29T09:12:41.235151+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=pacific-dawn-2489.herokuapp.com fwd="109.78.252.61" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-06-29T09:12:41.413239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=pacific-dawn-2489.herokuapp.com fwd="109.78.252.61" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-06-29T09:12:38.922579+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=pacific-dawn-2489.herokuapp.com fwd="109.78.252.61" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-06-29T09:12:50.528089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=pacific-dawn-2489.herokuapp.com fwd="109.78.252.61" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-06-29T09:12:50.689987+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=pacific-dawn-2489.herokuapp.com fwd="109.78.252.61" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your logs (t's an art to read 'em - you'll improve), it seems from the above that you have this error:

`/app/config/environments/production.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected keyword_in, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)`

Check out your `app/config/environments/production.rb` - I bet you'll find your mistake there.

And it probably never surfaced locally because you didn't run in production mode.

Comment: I've seen this before from people doing the Hartls tutorial, same error. For some reason `See everything in the log` in production.rb is missing a `#` at the front.